# python-pip requirement, trying to install a Python 2.7 package

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install Cuckoo Sandbox 2.0.7 on Ubuntu 20.04.4

The docs page advises this package only runs in Python 2.7:
https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/requirements.html#installing-python-libraries-on-ubuntu-debian-based-distributions

I have created a Virtual Environment and made sure Python 2.7 is installed inside it with anaconda.

The Docs Install guides list 'python-pip' as a requirement, however trying to install that returns a message telling me that it is obsolete, and to install 'python3-pip'.

I understand python-pip is in fact obsolete, but also that I should not use 'python3-pip', as the Cuckoo Package only works with Python 2.7.

Is it simply out of date information on the Cuckoo website, asking me to install something that is obsolete ?

Inside my Venv I can 'which' and '--version' pip, and am told it sits in /myVenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7). So 'pip' is ready if I need it.

I have googled the difference between 'pip' and 'python-pip', but not been able to uncover much. Can someone tell me the difference ? and will 'pip' do the same job as what the now obsolete 'python-pip' did, and can I ignore the requirement to install 'python-pip'.
I presume as my pip sits inside the 2.7 environment it will install cuckoo correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`python-pip`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-pip) is a package you install on Debian/Ubuntu with `apt`/`apt-get`/`aptitude`/`dselect`. In the current stable version (Debian 11 bullseye) the package was renamed to [`python-pip-whl`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python-pip-whl).

`pip` is the name of the package in Python distribution and [at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). Debian's `python-pip-whl` is built from the same sources, perhaps a slightly different version.

`pip` is also the name of the executable script and the name of the importable module. The script imports the module to do the job. Running `python -m pip` bypasses the script and directly runs the module.

Answer (score 0):

As @phd has already spelled out `python-pip` was simply the name of the package that installed `pip` for a python that comes pre-installed or was installed with `apt`.

You mention that you have anaconda and that `pip` already exists in the venv. This serves the same need. You now have a pip installed for the python interpreter in your environment. You should be able to activate your conda env and then run

```
pip install cuckoo
```